# How do I launch a function and wait/don't wait on it depending on whether it's a GUI application?

Tags: python, windows, process

I'm looking for a Python function which behaves just like the Windows command interpreter `cmd.exe` when it comes to waiting for newly launched processes to finish. Right now I'm using  `os.system()` but this function always blocks, even when launching GUI applications (which, in case they were written in C/C++, have a `WinMain` function and were linked with `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS`).

What code should I be using for launching external processes in case I *do* want the function to block when launching console applications, but I *do not* want it to block when launching GUI applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a small C wrapper/extension that checks for the subsystem (using `ImageNtHeader`). If all else fails, you can parse the PE headers directly.

Comment: start isn't a program (in an executable file). It's a command in the command interpreter.

Comment: +1: This is unfortunately the only solution I see so far. :-/

Comment: Actually, it shouldn't be extremely hard to write a simple extension if you can use something like Boost.Python.

Answer (score 0):

Python has no standard way to examine the executables you can start with the process API.

How about you start the external command using `cmd.exe`? Or create a BAT script in `%TEMP%` and run that.

Comment: Launching an external process via `cmd /C` doesn't seem to be the same. For instance, running `notepad` directly returns to the prompt immediately. Running `cmd /C notepad` waits until notepad finished before returning.

Comment: Isn't DOS fun? Well, in that case you'll need to teach Python what the command will do after starting it, so it can execute it with `cmd /C start/b` to run it in the background without waiting.